# how to solve "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" error message

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I build a simple app with angular8 and i  got this error when i use a model to my component.ts.I don't know why this happen.Anyone can help me to solve this??I make all the classes without any error message.but when i run it on the browser.It shows error message below

```
./src/app/test-form/test-form.component.ts 7:70
Module parse failed: Invalid number (7:70)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     constructor() {
|         this.topics = ['Angular', 'React', 'Vue'];
>         this.userModel = new User('galih', 'galihindra650@gmail.com', 082312514, '', 'morning', true);
|     }
|     ngOnInit() {
```

this is my component code

```
import { User } from '../model/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-form',
  templateUrl: './test-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-form.component.css']
})

export class TestFormComponent implements OnInit {
  topics = ['Angular', 'React', 'Vue'];
  userModel = new User('galih', 'galihindra650@gmail.com', 082312514, '', 'morning', true);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Class User

```
export class User {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
        public phone: number,
        public topic: string,
        public timePreference: string,
        public subscribe: boolean
    ) { }
}
```

html for the component

```
<div class="container-fluid col-6">
    <h3>Tes Form</h3>
    <form #userForm="ngForm">
        {{ userForm.value | json }} <br>User model : {{ userModel|json }}
        <!-- <div ngModelGroup="address">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" required class="form-control" ngModel name="city">
                <small class="text-danger">Name is required</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label> Street</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ngModel name="street">
            </div>

        </div> -->
        <!-- Biar value setiam input bisa terbaca harus pake ngModel dan dikasih name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name" name="name">
            <small class="text-danger">Name is required</small>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.email" name="email">

. . .
```

Comment: Try to use `82312514` instead of `082312514`

Comment: it works!...as simple as that?

Comment: Actually, phone number is more like a string, not a number. 082312514 is a valid phone number, but not valid instance of number type. In this particular case the one with 0 may call to correct person, one without not.